# Why doesn't sysout work?

Tags: java

I've been using eclipse for a while learning java but when I type sysout it generally shows println, but now its showing

```
private void sysout()
```

when it's supposed to show

```
System.out.println();
```

anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: @Trobbins Thanks, I'll delete. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completion to use in Eclipse is `syso`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This is context-sensitive and needs to be used in a place where a `System.out.println` call is valid (i.e. in a method, constructor, initializer block, or lambda)

Comment: Gotcha.  I was putting outside of the main method of my program.

Comment: @WesleyLuh I've had the same issue, I'd wish it would give me a slap on the wrist when I try to do so instead of trying to make a method.

Answer (score 1):

Type `syso` then `ctrl-space` for the shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Type "sysout" or "sys" and press `ctrl+space`. Suggesation list will show where you will find sysout -> System.out.println(). Select that. If your write sysout and press `ctrl+space` then it will directly write System.out.println().